# Can gdb log all instructions and their addresses solely within a particular shared library?

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

Using gdb I wish to log all instructions and their addresses - and preferably register values before and after each instruction if possible - but only within a library. I am debugging an Android application and can break and step within the library but I'd like to more or less automate the collection of instructions and register values within said library. I am connected to gdb on an Android emulator via gdbserver on the Android instance and gdb with remote target on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

> Can gdb log all instructions and their addresses solely within a particular shared library?

It can, but doing this will be *excruciatingly* slow.

Also, there is no *easy* way to do this: you will have to use [embedded Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Python.html#Python) and write script to print whatever data you want.